# Proper gas pressure for Samsung DV457GVGSGR natural gas dryer

Tags: appliances, natural-gas

What is the proper gas pressure leading into my Samsung model DV457GVGSGR gas dryer?  The Gas Requirements section of the installation manual doesn't specify pressure.

[image]

I found this in a google search, but the page is now missing (goes to 404 error).  The text snipped seems to recommend 3.5 to 5 inches of water column.  Is that correct?

[image]

Can I damage my dryer by sending 2 PSIG of gas pressure without a regulator?  How much should I send to the dryer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5" WC is a reasonable pressure which is about 0.18 PSI. There should be a sticker on the dryer that will say what the max inlet pressure.

Sending 2PSI without a regulator will likely damage the dryer or not have it work correctly. It'll probably blow the flame out and never dry your clothes.

Comment: I've been running the dryer for 3 years with no regulator, so it seems to be working fine at my house.

Answer (score 0):

Nominal line pressure after your gas meter should be "around 7 inches of water column (WC) or re-stating this in equivalent measure, that's 14.9 millibars or 1743 Pascals or Pa, or about 0.25 psi (pounds per square inch) or about 4 ounces of pressure per square inch."  If you are seeing 2 psi, call your utility provider (may not be the same as your NG supplier) and request they come check the function of the pressure regulator supplying your meter.